# Tyr's Hand - Rule Check

Tags: android-netrunner

I have [Tyr's Hand](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03022) installed in a remote server and [Heimdall 2.0](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03015) protecting it. The runner declares a run and approaches [Heimdall 2.0](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03015). I pay to rez the ice, and the runner decides to break all three subroutines with whatever means are at her disposal.

Is it correct that [Tyr's Hand](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03022) can be rezzed and trashed now to prevent the runner from breaking the second subroutine (1 brain damage, end the run)? And is it correct that essentially the runner has no way of avoiding this from happening - once they have elected to break a subroutine, I can prevent them from breaking it and they must suffer the consequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tyr's Hand should be rezzed after the runner encounters a piece of bioroid ice and declares that they are going to break subroutines on that ice (usually via clicks/breakers).  So, in your example, you would rez Heimdall 2.0 first, and if the runner declares that they are going to break the subs, then you would rez Tyr's Hand.  So, you don't have to rez Tyr's Hand when you rez the ICE (which might be useful if they see Heimdall can't break anything anyways).

When the runner declares that they are breaking, you can rez Tyr's hand and trash it to prevent one subroutine from being broken.  This means: whatever the runner spent to break that subroutine is still spent (e.g. 2 clicks from 2.0 ICE, or credits) - however, they can still spend more to rebreak the subroutine.  So, if they used a breaker - perhaps it just costs them an extra credit.  But if they were relying on clicks, then they are out of luck!

Comment: OK, so if they approached Viktor 1.0 with two clicks left, and decided to use both clicks to break both subroutines, I can rez Tyr's Hand and trash it. If I picked the brain damage subroutine they could still pay to break it again, but with no clicks left... bad luck?

Comment: Exactly.  In other words, if they hit Viktor 1.0 with 3 clicks left (running first click), and declare they are spending 2 clicks to break both subroutines, you can rez Tyr's Hand to stop from one break... but they can still use their 4th click to rebreak it.

Comment: +1! I don't know if there are good options out there for Netrunner, but if this were an analogous MtG question a great answer would be supported with a keyword and comprehensive rules quote. *If* there's a similarly official source to back up your explanation, it would be awesome to include it.